# Small Gap on Safari when using transform: translateX

Tags: css, firefox, safari

I am using transform: translateX in order to be able to create a sliding effect.

The code works fine under Chrome.

In safari, in some screen resolutions and sometimes under firefox I get a small gap during the animation.

When the animated layer stops the gap dissapears.

Initially I have a

```
-moz-transform: translateX(100%);
-ms-transform: translateX(100%);
-o-transform: translateX(100%);
transform: translateX(100%);
```

And after hover, I have a:

```
-moz-transform: translateX(0%);
-ms-transform: translateX(0%);
-o-transform: translateX(0%);
transform: translateX(0%);
```

I have a makeup of my code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/e197mrsb/40/

I would be grateful if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

use margin 0 on hover class .....

Comment: Unfortunately,  this doesn't make any difference :-(